# Java MYSQL Prepared Statement Error: Check syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to use the java mysql library but I am having issues using a prepared statement. I am not sure what I am missing. Below is what I have with the MYSQL error attempting to use the prepared statement.

```
String query = "SELECT id, clicks FROM mailer.links WHERE campaign_id=?";
    try {

        preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, campaignId);
        preparedStatement.execute();
        Statement st = connect.createStatement();


        // execute the query, and get a java resultset
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

It works if I do "campaign_id=" + campaignId , but is a SQL injection waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();`

Answer (score 0):

`PreparedStatement` method `executeQuery()` itself returns a ResultSet object

So assign this to a `ResultSet` object

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

And this error happens because When

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

This statement executes it can't find any value in `?` operator.
so your query remains this  `"SELECT id, clicks FROM mailer.links WHERE campaign_id=?";` and this throws a MySQL Syntax Exception.